# How to send email with PHP's mail() function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, email, function

I have made a small code that does not send any email. It gives me a blank page. Any suggestions?

```
<?php 
$result_array1 = array();
$result_array2 = array();
$result_array3 = array();
$result_array4 = array();
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  `test_thing`";
$result1 = mysql_query("$sql1") or die($sql1.mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
   $result_array1[] = $row1['email'];
   $result_array2[] = $subject;
   $result_array3[] = $message;
   $result_array4[] = $header;
}
$sentmail = mail($result_array1,$result_array2,$result_array3,$result_array4);
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
It gives me a blank page.
```

Actually it should. You don't use output functions in code you shown. If you expected error messages, make sure you have [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) enabled and [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to `E_ALL`

Answer (score 4):

Mail takes strings as arguments, not arrays.  You'll need to do a for loop and call mail on each array for its index.

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
   $result_array1[] = $row1['email'];
   $result_array2[] = $subject;
   $result_array3[] = $message;
   $result_array4[] = $header;
}
```

I expect you mean:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
   $result_array1 = $row1['email'];
   $result_array2 = $subject;
   $result_array3 = $message;
   $result_array4 = $header;
}
```

`mail()` expects strings. Unless you are meaning to loop through and send multiple mails, then you need to re-design your code a bit.

Comment: can you give me a hint how to re-design the code a bit because I mean to loop and send multiple mails
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is your complete code, your database is not initialized correctly. Read the documentation on [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) for more information and examples.

Also, try echoing out some debug data to see you're actually getting some data out of the database.

Comment: my full code is about 500 lines long, this is just a very small part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do

```
<?php 
  $result_array1 = array();
  $result_array2 = array();
  $result_array3 = array();
  $result_array4 = array();
  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  `test_thing`";
  $result1 = mysql_query("$sql1") or die($sql1.mysql_error());
  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
    $sentmail = mail($row1['email'],$subject,$message,$header);
  }
?>
```

Comment: because this way a user receives unlimited emails

Answer (score 0):

I think you more than one problem here.
First you must connect to the database. As in Answer 1, read php manual for mysql interface, specially function mysql_connect.
Second, the while is in fact wrong.
While (x = any_function) does not attribute any_function result to variable 'x'. 'x = any_function' returns a boolean value, nothing else.
You sould write something like:
while ((x = any_function())) or in your case:
while(($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)))
where '$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)' attributes to $rows1 values returned by mysql_fecth_array and
'($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))' returns a boolean value to controle the while construct.
I hope I've helped you.